# Why is it possible to build a Haskell program with .hs files that fail to compile individually?

Tags: haskell

I am relatively new to Haskell and the compile/build process. I cloned a Haskell package from Github that builds using a cabal file. I can build the program no problem using `stack build`, `stack install` etc.

Currently I am interested in using the functions in only the Rewrite.hs file in the Haskell package, but I cannot successfully compile it by importing Rewrite to my own Main.hs and calling `ghc Main.hs`. I get the following type errors:

```
Rewrite.hs:73:13: error:
    • Expecting one more argument to ‘Module’
      Expected a type, but ‘Module’ has kind ‘* -> *’
    • In the type signature:
        stripTop :: Module -> Module

Rewrite.hs:16:29: error:
    • Expecting one more argument to ‘Pat’
      Expected a type, but ‘Pat’ has kind ‘* -> *’
    • In the type signature:
        findPats :: Data a => a -> [Pat]
```

I thought that building a package basically compiles and links files together - Why is it possible to have compiler errors for parts of a program when compiling by hand? Alternatively, should I not be attempting to use a .hs file from a part of a program like this?

EDITED:

The package is https://github.com/Genetic-Strictness/Autobahn

An example of Main:

```
import Rewrite
import System.FilePath
import Language.Haskell.Exts

file ::FilePath
file = "test.hs"

main = placesToStrict file
```

where the function `placesToStrict` is from Rewrite which calls on `findPats`, which causes the compiler errors above.

Comment: Probably stack compiles with some flags. Can you show the stack file?

Comment: Can you please link the package you used for this, and also post your (minimal) `Main.hs` that you are compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .cabal file specifies several language extensions: `other-extensions:    BangPatterns, FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeSynonymInstances`

You can enabled these on a per file basis by putting: `{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns, FlexibleInstances, ... #-}` at the top of your source file. You can also pass `-XBangPatterns -XFlexibleInstances ...` to ghc, although this is discouraged.

Comment: I realized that ghc and stack were using different versions of the same package. Thanks!